# What crystal is this? Marked T480

Tags: crystal

[image]

I think this is a Kyocera [CX3225SB48000D0FPJC1](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/909/kyocera_09112019_CX3225SB-1648541.pdf), but the marked codes don't match the datasheet.

- First line marking : T480
- Second line marking : Mv9T

What is this crystal?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that's a [TXC 8Z](https://www.txccrystal.com/images/pdf/8z.pdf) series 48MHz crystal, not a Kyocera.

Photo from quartzcrystal.cn

[image]

I don't see detailed info on the bottom line markings- it certainly includes a date code. The tolerance, stability, and load capacitance may or may not be encoded.